# ChatBot for html website

Tags: php, jquery, html, chatbot

i need to add a chatbot like this one http://www.tchat-tarot.com/ to my website do you have an idea what kind of plugin this website is using ?
Thank you

Comment: Looks custom to me, or they've taken some third party code and minified it into their own env.  There's a chatb.js that they load from their own servers.

Comment: Yes i think it's custom too , i just wanted to be sure so i don't do extra work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a custom piece. You should look at some alternatives like https://api.ai/ or https://wit.ai/ They are fairly easy to implement and you can customize various outputs based on keywords, plus they have machine learning capabilities as well.